# Octave Real time plotting

Tags: c++, plot, real-time, octave

for my project I've a C++ script which returns every 5ms, an error ( a double number ). this error is saved into a txt file. 
Is it possible use Octave and create a real time plot that show me the error dynamic while the C++ script is running?

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried to poll the file in a loop and plot it?